# Generate "select Statement" output as text formate using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I am a novice to VB.net, and am trying to write a small program that saves the output of a `SELECT` into a text file. I am using SQL Server.

For example, consider the statement

```
   SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE;
```

Comment: how far have you gotten? show where you are stuck

Comment: Without more information, the best I can say is that you should look into [System.IO.StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx) This is the standard way of writing a text file.

Comment: This is somewhat broad, you should be a little more specific.

Comment: (1) Please do yourself a favour and set [Option Strict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) to On, now and as the default setting for new projects. (2) As Steve implied, `Scripting.FileSystemObject` is not the .NET way of accessing files.

Comment: First, you need to type your variables. This will help give you help (intellisense) in your code. Second, try `DebugFile.WriteLine(strLine)`. Just make sure after your loop, you close the file by doing a `DebugFile.Flush` and `DebugFile.close`